# Force Convertto-html to only include an object's "MemberType" "property"

Tags: powershell

I have an array of system.data.datarow objects. Now the properties of these objects have the info I want. When I pass these objects to convertto-html though it picks up all this extra crap and I see rows with names like RowError,RowState,Table- when all I want is the objects properties.

Is there a way I can only include the object's properties to be converted to html (meaning if I do a Get-Member on the object the "MemberType" property).

Can I convert these objects to generic psobjects without having to loop through them all and rebuild them with New-Object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab the names of all the `Property`-type properties with `Get-Member` and `Select-Object`:

```
$Props = Get-Member -InputObject $DataRowObjects[0] -MemberType Property | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
$Html = $DataRowObjects | Select-Object -Property $Props | ConvertTo-Html
```

Comment: select-object wasn't working for me that why I asked about casting them to a generic objects. I already am doing a select-object to filter out the columns (or object properties) I want so manual specifying the properties isn't an issue, but when I send the objects to convertto-html it picks up all this other stuff. Its something specific to that cmdlet because convertto-csv works as expected (it doesn't including anything other than the objects properties).

Comment: I can reproduce what you describe with `$DataRowObjects | ConvertTo-Html`, but when I do the select just before piping to `ConvertTo-Html`, it works as you expect: `$DataRowObjects | Select-Object -Property $Props | ConvertTo-Html`

Comment: hmm should have test that first I guess sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem with the accepted answer is that it changes the order of the fields to alphabetical from the given field names

To avoid and keep the original order from the select statement, I used the following approach

```
$unwantedColumns = @('RowError','RowState','Table','ItemArray','HasErrors') # these guys get added automatically by Invoke-SqlCmd

$props = $sqlResult.PSObject.Properties.Name | Where-Object {$_ -NotIn $unwantedColumns}

$htmlBody = $sqlResult |
        Select-Object -Property $props |
        ConvertTo-Html @ConvertToHtmlArgs |
        Out-String
```